# Setting the alpha channel of an image, based on the pixel values in another image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, bitwise-operators, alpha-transparency

I have two images. In one image all non-alpha channel pixels are equal to 0, and I'd like the alpha channel values to equal 255 where in the other image which is of equal size, the pixels are anything but 0. In this attempt, I'm attempting to create a 4 channel np array based off of the original image, and then use np.argwhere to find where the pixel valeus are non-zero, and then in the new np array, set the alpha channel value based on that.

For example, for each pixel in my input image with values [255, 255, 255], I'd like the corresponding pixel in my new image to be [0, 0, 0, 255]. For each pixel in my input image with values [0, 0, 0], I'd like the corresponding pixel in my new image to be [0, 0, 0, 0].

```
mask_file = cv.imread(r'PlateMask_0001.png', cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

scale_factor = 0.125
w = int(mask_file.shape[1] * scale_factor)
h = int(mask_file.shape[0] * scale_factor)
scaled = cv.resize(mask_file, (w, h))

coords = np.argwhere(scaled > 0)
new_object = np.zeros((120, 160, 4))
new_object[coords, :] = 255
cv.imshow('Mask', mask)
cv.imshow('Scaled', new_object)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is my first question on Stack so please feel free to suggest improvements on question formatting, etc. Thank you.

Comment: If the two images are the same size, then just extract the alpha channel from the one image and apply it to the other image.

Comment: @fmw42 That is the task that I am attempting to do, and asking help for on. However, I like your wording better, thank you.

Comment: Your statement of the problem is not clear to me. What does the alpha channel of the old image have to do with setting values in the new image, since you are specifying the exact values you want based upon the values in the old image without any alpha values in the old image.

Comment: @fmw42 I should have clarified, there is no alpha channel in the base image, only the standard three of an RGB Image. I just needed to essentially map all of the locations of non-zero pixels in the base image to a 255 value in the secondary images alpha values. This odd task was required to provide area labels to a autoML platforms auto-labeling SDK from a set of sample/label images that were of a different format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider `img1` to be your original image and `img2` to be the image where alpha channel needs to be modified.

In the following, the alpha channel of `img2` contains value 255 in the coordinate where `img1` has (255, 255, 255):

```
img2[:,:,3][img1 == (255, 255, 255)]  = 255
```

Likewise for value 0:

```
img2[:,:,3][img1 == (0, 0, 0)]  = 0
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you for breaking it down for me in the explanation. I also like the notation of your solution. I think that the contrast between normal slicing, and reaching the different channels of an image was the concept that was confusing me.